# If a framework is available for multiple platforms, should we re-use sub-tags for it's components?

Tags: discussion

If a framework is available for multiple platforms, should we re-use sub-tags for it's components?

On SO, I watch the [spring.net tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring.net). Spring.NET is a port of Java's well known Spring framework. Amongst others, Spring.NET supports Aop and an expression language, just like Spring for Java does.

Is it appropriate to use [spring-aop](/questions/tagged/spring-aop) and [spring-el](/questions/tagged/spring-el) on [spring.net](/questions/tagged/spring.net) questions, even though the tag descriptions for [spring-aop](/questions/tagged/spring-aop) and [spring-el](/questions/tagged/spring-el) explicitly refer to Spring for java?